# Why range of my variable is limited into "tail -f scope"?

Tags: bash, variables, scope

I have application which register OnLine or Offline status which is stored in my test.log file. Status can be changed every second or minute or at all during many hours. Once per 15 minutes I need to send actual status to external machine [my.ip.address]. In below example let's assume that I need to just echo actual status.

I wrote below script which is watching my test.log and stores **actual status in FLAG variable**. However I cannot send it (or echo) to my external machine [my.ip.address] cause FLAG is not saved properly. **Do you have any idea what's wrong in below example?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FLAG="OffLine"
FLAG_tmp=$FLAG

tail -f /my/path/test.log | while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *"OnLine"* ]]; then
        FLAG_tmp="OnLine"
    fi

    if [[ $line == *"OffLine"* ]]; then
        FLAG_tmp="OffLine"
    fi

    if [ "$FLAG" != "$FLAG_tmp" ];then
        FLAG=$FLAG_tmp
        echo $FLAG      # it works, now FLAG stores actual true status
    fi

done &

# till this line I suppose that everything went well but here (I mean out of
# tail -f scope) $FLAG stores only OffLine - even if I change it to OnLine 4 lines before.

while :
do
    #(echo $FLAG > /dev/udp/[my.ip.address]/[port])
    echo "$FLAG"     # for debug purpose - just echo actual status. 
                    # However it is always OffLine! WHY?
    #sleep 15*60    # wait 15 minutes
    sleep 2         # for debug, wait only 2 sec
done
```

EDIT:
Thanks guys for your answers, but I still don't get a solution.

**@123**: I corrected my code basing on your example, but it seems to not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FLAG="OffLine"
FLAG_tmp=$FLAG

while read line
do
if [[ $line == *"OnLine"* ]]; then
    FLAG_tmp="OnLine"
fi

if [[ $line == *"OffLine"* ]]; then
    FLAG_tmp="OffLine"
fi

if [ "$FLAG" != "$FLAG_tmp" ];then
    FLAG=$FLAG_tmp
    #echo $FLAG
fi
done & < <(tail -f /c/vagrant_data/iso/rpos/log/rpos.log)

while :
do
    echo "$FLAG"
    sleep 2
done
```

**@chepner**: Do you have some exact proposals how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The _pipeline_ (`|`) you introduced creates a sub-shell and variables updated in sub-shell are _not_ reflected in the parent shell.

Comment: OK, but how can I manage this issue? maybe by exporting it? Do you have some proposals?

Comment: `while;do stuff;done < <(tail -f /my/path/test.log)`

Comment: Process substitution won't help; you are also running the entire thing in a background process with `&`.

Comment: This isn't an issue of scope, which describes the lifetime of a variable within a single program. This is an issue of interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it overly complicated. If you just want to send yourself the last state of OffLine or OnLine you might try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    FLAG="$(egrep 'OffLine|OnLine' test.log | tail -1)"

    if [ $(echo "$FLAG" | grep OffLine) ]
    then
        FLAG=OffLine
    else
        FLAG=OnLine
    fi

    echo $FLAG
    sleep 2
done
```

Or, if you really want to keep the two processes,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo OffLine > status
tail -f test.log | while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ "OffLine" ]] 
    then
        echo OffLine > status
    elif [[ "$line" =~ "OnLine" ]]
    then
        echo OnLine > status
    fi
 done &

 while :
 do
     cat status > /dev/udp/[my.ip.address]/[port])
     sleep 15*60
 done
```

Comment: I hope to meet you personally to solemnly thank you very much! You really safe my time and give great idea how to solve it. That is perfect solution (especially the second one with writing to status file). Once again, thank you for your time :-)